# Java Graphics - Something simple like Zelle's Graphics for Python

Tags: java, graphics

I am new to Java and I just wanted to get something simple that might be similar to [Zelle's graphics](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics.pdf) for Python.

Answer (score 2):

The Java classes [Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html) and [Graphics2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) should contain most of what Zelle's graphics contains.

Here's some Java Swing code to get you started.  This Java application will draw with your mouse as long as you hold down the left mouse button.  When you release the left mouse button, the screen erases and you can draw something else.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class DrawingTest implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private MyDrawPanel drawPanel;

    private List<Point> points;

    public DrawingTest() {
        points = new ArrayList<Point>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame("Bouncing Vertices");

        drawPanel = new MyDrawPanel(this);
        MyListener alpha = new MyListener(this);
        drawPanel.addMouseMotionListener(alpha);
        drawPanel.addMouseListener(alpha);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel getDrawingPanel() {
        return drawPanel;
    }

    public List<Point> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoint(int x, int y) {
        points.add(new Point(x, y));
    }

    public void resetPoints() {
        points.clear();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DrawingTest());
    }

    private class MyListener extends MouseInputAdapter {

        private DrawingTest drawingTest;

        public MyListener(DrawingTest drawingTest) {
            this.drawingTest = drawingTest;
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            drawingTest.setPoint(event.getX(), event.getY());
            drawingTest.getDrawingPanel().repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            drawingTest.resetPoints();
        }

    }

    private class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private DrawingTest drawingTest;

        public MyDrawPanel(DrawingTest drawingTest) {
            this.drawingTest = drawingTest;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            for (int i = 1; i < drawingTest.getPoints().size(); i++) {
                Point p1 = drawingTest.getPoints().get(i - 1);
                Point p2 = drawingTest.getPoints().get(i);
                g.drawLine(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The last method in the code, the paintComponent method, is where you use the Graphics methods.